# Root log all level

Tags: c#, asp.net, logging, log4net, log4net-configuration

My root logger catches all levels of log except `off`. My level is set to `INFO`. 
I searched if the level was changed somewhere, but I found nothing.

When I put the logger `IBatisNet.DataMapper.Commands.DefaultPreparedCommand` to `DEBUG`, the log is created in a text file by `SpecificAppender`. But, the log also appears in the console even if the root is set to `INFO`.

This is my code:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!-- This section contains the log4net configuration settings -->
<configuration>
<configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler,     log4net" />
</configSections>
<log4net>
    <!-- Define some output appenders -->
    <appender name="RollingLogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
        <param name="File" value="d:/logs/vol/vol.log" />
        <param name="AppendToFile" value="true" />
        <param name="MaxSizeRollBackups" value="3" />
        <param name="MaximumFileSize" value="500KB" />
        <param name="RollingStyle" value="Size" />
        <param name="StaticLogFileName" value="true" />

        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{HH:mm:ss,fff} [%t] %-5p %c{1} - %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <appender name="IBatisAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
        <param name="File" value="d:/logs/vol/IBatis.log" />
        <param name="AppendToFile" value="true" />
        <param name="MaxSizeRollBackups" value="3" />
        <param name="MaximumFileSize" value="1000KB" />
        <param name="RollingStyle" value="Size" />
        <param name="StaticLogFileName" value="true" />

        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{HH:mm:ss,fff} [%t] %-5p %c{1} - %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <appender name="ConsoleAppender" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{HH:mm:ss,fff} [%t] %-5p %c{1} - %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <appender name="IBatisBufferingAppender" type="log4net.Appender.BufferingForwardingAppender" >
        <bufferSize value="60"/>
        <appender-ref ref="IBatisAppender" />
    </appender>

    <appender name="LogBufferingAppender" type="log4net.Appender.BufferingForwardingAppender" >
        <bufferSize value="60"/>
        <appender-ref ref="RollingLogFileAppender" />
    </appender>

    <appender name="SpecificAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
        <file value="d:/logs/vol/" />
        <appendToFile value="true"/>
        <datePattern value="Volu\me\trieSpeci\fic_yyyy-MM-dd.lo\g"/>
        <rollingStyle value="Date"/>
        <maxSizeRollBackups value="30"/>
        <appendToFile value="true"/>
        <staticLogFileName value="false"/>
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{HH:mm:SS,fff} [%t] %-5p %c{1} - %m%n" />
        </layout>
        <filter type="log4net.Filter.StringMatchFilter">
            <stringToMatch value="No -->"/>
            <acceptOnMatch value ="true" />
        </filter>
        <filter type="log4net.Filter.StringMatchFilter">
            <stringToMatch value="Statement Id: [vol.Delete"/>
            <acceptOnMatch value ="false" />
        </filter>
        <filter type="log4net.Filter.StringMatchFilter">
            <stringToMatch value="] Types: ["/>
            <acceptOnMatch value ="false" />
        </filter>
        <filter type="log4net.Filter.StringMatchFilter">
            <stringToMatch value="Statement Id: [vol."/>
            <acceptOnMatch value ="true" />
        </filter>
        <filter type="log4net.Filter.DenyAllFilter"/>
    </appender>

    <root>
        <level value="INFO" />
        <appender-ref ref="ConsoleAppender" />
        <appender-ref ref="LogBufferingAppender" />
    </root>

    <logger name="PROGvolBatch.Services.CIService">
        <level value="INFO" />
        <appender-ref ref="SpecificAppender"/>
    </logger>

    <logger name="IBatisNet.DataMapper.Commands.DefaultPreparedCommand">
        <level value="DEBUG" />
        <appender-ref ref="SpecificAppender"/>
    </logger>

    <logger name="IBatisNet.DataMapper.Configuration.Cache.CacheModel">
        <level value="OFF" />
        <appender-ref ref="IBatisBufferingAppender" />
    </logger>
    <logger name="IBatisNet.DataMapper.LazyLoadList">
        <level value="OFF" />
        <appender-ref ref="IBatisBufferingAppender" />
    </logger>
    <logger name="IBatisNet.DataMapper.SqlMapSession">
        <level value="OFF" />
        <appender-ref ref="IBatisBufferingAppender" />
    </logger>
    <logger name="IBatisNet.Common.Transaction.TransactionScope">
        <level value="OFF" />
        <appender-ref ref="IBatisBufferingAppender" />
    </logger>
    <logger name="IBatisNet.DataAccess.DaoSession">
        <level value="OFF" />
        <appender-ref ref="IBatisBufferingAppender" />
    </logger>
    <logger name="IBatisNet.DataAccess.Configuration.DaoProxy">
        <level value="OFF" />
        <appender-ref ref="IBatisBufferingAppender" />
    </logger>
    <logger name="IBatisNet.DataMapper.Configuration.Statements.PreparedStatementFactory">
        <level value="OFF" />
        <appender-ref ref="IBatisBufferingAppender" />
    </logger>
    <logger name="IBatisNet.DataMapper.Commands.IPreparedCommand">
        <level value="OFF" />
        <appender-ref ref="IBatisBufferingAppender" />
    </logger>
</log4net>
```

I tried changing the level of the root to something else, but I always got the same result.

Comment: What is the problem? Please state clearly what you need, and what is happening.

Comment: When I put the logger "IBatisNet.DataMapper.Commands.DefaultPreparedCommand" to DEBUG, the log are created in a text file by SpecificAppender. But, the log also appear in the console even if the root is set to INFO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be the way log4net works. When your config file is processed it behaves as if it has been configured like:

```xml
<logger name="IBatisNet.DataMapper.Commands.DefaultPreparedCommand" additivity="false">
    <level value="DEBUG" />
    <appender-ref ref="SpecificAppender"/>
    <appender-ref ref="ConsoleAppender" />
    <appender-ref ref="LogBufferingAppender" />
</logger>
```

Fortunately there is a workaround and that is to set a level filter on your appenders, e.g. for the ConsoleAppender:

```xml
 <appender name="ConsoleAppender" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender">
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{HH:mm:ss,fff} [%t] %-5p %c{1} - %m%n" />
  </layout>
  <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter">
    <levelMin value="INFO" />
    <acceptOnMatch value="true" />
  </filter>    
</appender>
```

It might also be better to rename the appender to something more descriptive like `InfoConsoleAppender`. Also, if you want to be able to log some loggers to console at debug level, then you may need another un-filtered `ConsoleAppender`.